# Best Way to Read in URL parameters Into Python WSGI Web Application

Tags: python-3.x, apache, wsgi

I am trying to run my Python 3.6 report code inside of Apache 2.4 via WSGI. I finally got it working under Linux in daemon mode with WSGI.

My next hurdle is what is the best way to parse the URL that called my script in Python so that I can read the browser URL parameters? i.e.

```
www.myapp.com/wsgi/?parameter1=Larry&parameter2=Moe&parameter3=Curly
```

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago you asked, but did you already found cgi?
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/cgi.html